# Как в opencart2 показать количество товаров в карте товара?

Tags: excel, opencart

Там написано " в наличии", а как сделать отображение точного количества?
И еще, как сделать, чтоб количество бралось с файлика экселя?

Answer (score 0):

В `controller/product/product.php` добавить `$data['quantity'] = $product_info['quantity'];`

В `view/theme/default(your_theme)/product.tpl` в нужном месте добавить `<?=$quantity;?>`

Comment: огромное спасибо. кому интересно, $data['quantity'] = $product_info['quantity'];  вставил после 274 строки.